# What is the connection between metric distances and the norm in a normed vector space in the given example?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $v_{0}$ be the space containing each sequence $y = (y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} y_{n} = 0$, equipped with the norm $\Vert y \Vert_{\infty} = \sup_{n} |y_{n}|$.

I'm having difficulty understanding the connection between metric distances and the norm in a normed vector space. So considering the vector space above, do we write $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} y_{n} = 0$ as $\Vert y_{n} - 0 \Vert < \epsilon $ for all $n \ge N$? Where $\Vert y_{n} - 0 \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm of each point of the sequence $y$ to $0$. Then, is the sup norm just greater than or equal to the Euclidean norm?

Comment: The metric $d$ induced by a norm $\|\cdot\|$ is defined as $$d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: I'm not really sure what it means for a metric to be induced by a norm

Comment: By definition, the metric $d$ induced by a norm $\| \cdot\|$ is defined as previously said. If you have a norm, you can define a distance using this norm.

Comment: @Tuvasbien: Then for the example given, the distance using the norm given is $\sup_{n}|y_{n} - 0|$?

Comment: The distance woulde be $d(u,v)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|u_n-v_n|$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien: I forgot to put infinity at the bottom left of $\Vert y \Vert$ to get $\Vert y \Vert_{\infty}$. Are there any changes to how $d(u,v)$ is defined, or is this just another name for the norm of the given vector space?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ are two different norms, thus $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ and $d_{\infty}(u,v)=\|u-v\|_{\infty}$ are two different metrics. Moreover $d_{\infty}$ is defined on $v_0^2$ but $d$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus $\|y_n\|$ makes no sense !

Comment: @Tuvasbien: do you mean that $d_{\infty}$ is defined on $v_{0}$?

Comment: Well $d_{\infty}$ has two entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A norm is a function from $X$ (vector space) to $\mathbb{R}+$, so, is a function that for each x $\in X$ you get a non-negative number.

While a metric is a function from $X$ x $X$ to $\mathbb{R}+$.

Your $v_0$ is a vector space where you can use the norm $||$ $\cdot $  $||_\infty$.

From a norm you always get a metric: $\rho(x,y)=||x-y||$.

Informally, the norm gives you a way to "measure" the "length" of a vector, while the metric gives you a "distance" between two points, and in a vector space, your points are vectors, and in this case, they are sequences.

Comment: In this case, the metric $\rho(x,y) = \Vert x-y \Vert = |x_{n}-y_{n}|$?

Comment: or is $\rho(x,y) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x_{n}-y_{n}|$?

Comment: In the case of the infinity norm: $\rho(x,y) = ||x-y||_\infty=sup_n |x_n-y_n|$

Comment: If we are not specificaly in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, try to not to think inmediatly that is the Euclidean norm